# Using jasmine to test amplifyjs request call backs

Tags: jasmine, amplifyjs

I'm using `amplifyjs` for AJAX requests. That's working fine. I'm using `jasmine` to test the code. I'm wondering what the best method is to test the success and error call backs. The current unit test I've written doesn't work because the call back is executed after the `jasmine` `expect`. Here's my code under test:

```
function logout() {
    ns.busy.show();

    amplify.request({
        resourceId: 'logout',
        success: _logoutSuccess
    });
};
function _logoutSuccess(response) {
    ns.busy.hide();
};
```

Here's the unit test, where I want to validate that a function is called when the request is returned:

```
it('should hide busy when successful', function () {
            // arrange
            ns.busy = { show: function () { }, hide: function () { } };
            spyOn(ns.busy, 'hide');
            amplify.request.define('logout', function (settings) {
                settings.success({});
            });

            // act
            ns.accountLogoutViewModel.logout();

            // assert
            expect(ns.busy.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

Note: `ns` is just a variable holding the application namespace. If I place break points on the `expect` and on the `ns.busy.hide()` in the `_logoutSuccess` function, `jasmine` hits the `expect` and then hits the `_logoutSuccess`, hence the `spyOn` fails.

As I say, the code is working, I just want to know how to write a test for it. I've looked into the `jasmine` `done()` function, but I'm not sure how to use it in this circumstance (or even if it is a solution).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it always the way, when I finally get round to posting a question, I then immediately find the answer. Here's the test that passes, using the `jasmine` `done()` function:

```
it('should hide busy when successful', function (done) {
            // arrange
            ns.busy = { show: function () { }, hide: function () { } };
            spyOn(ns.busy, 'hide');
            amplify.request.define('logout', function (settings) {
                settings.success({});
                done();
            });

            // act
            ns.accountLogoutViewModel.logout();

            // assert
            expect(ns.busy.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```